# How to put a link in an email

Tags: c#

When i send Forgot password mail to user to reset their password my mail & link is like this:

```html
<br><br>You have forgotten your password so here is a link to reset it:<br>
www.bla.com/test/ResetPasswordVertification?VertificationCode=ojlqidsgkxERoPy6vCQHZtJ9jLRaYA
```

But i Want something like this : You have forgotten your password [Click here](http://#) to reset it

I Tried to add an `<a>`-tag :

```
.Send("Reset Password ", "You have forgotten your password\n so here is link to reset it \n <a href=\"www.bla.dk/Account/loginResetPasswordVertification?VertificationCode=\">Click her</a>" 
    + user.VertificationCode 
    + "\n <br/> Best Regards \n ", 
    Email);
<br>
```

But My Result is like this:

> You have forgotten your password Click here =asdawdasdawdadw

The Code:

```
new MailHandler().Send("Reset Password", "You have forgotten your password \n so here is a link to reset it \n www.bla.com/test/ResetPasswordVertification?VertificationCode=" + user.VertificationCode, Email);
```

Comment: I don't know how a link is a "String & Value" or how a mail is a "tag" but most email clients accept html, just put in a html link to see if it works...

Comment: add an anchor-element around your text to be interpreted as link: `<a href="theLink">Click Here</a>`.

Comment: i did , but its gonna loook like this > You have forgotten your password Click here  =ojlqidsgkxERoPy6vCQHZtJ9jLRaYA to reset it

Comment: that link should be in the `href="RIGHT HERE"` just do `$"You have forgotten your password <a href=\"www.bla.com/test/ResetPasswordVertification?VertificationCode={user.VerificationCode}\"> Click here </a> to reset it"`

Comment: .Send("Reset Password ", "You have forgotten your password\n so here is link to reset it \n <a href=\"www.bla.dk/Account/loginResetPasswordVertification?VertificationCode=\">Klik her</a>" + user.VertificationCode + "\n <br/> Best Regards \n ", Email);

Comment: Please add code into your question, not into the comments, as it´s hard to read.

Comment: @HellorhighWater you dont have the `user.VerificationCode` in the `href`....

Comment: try code and let me know if you need any further help

Comment: @PranayRana I practically gave him the exact string he needs. If he still  does not get it please don't help or he will not learn anything

Comment: @HimBromBeere i just update the Question

Comment: @EpicKip - respect you ...ok...

Comment: @HellorhighWater Use the string I posed in a comment (the one in the code block) in combination with Pranay Rana's answer. It will work fine. You're doing the `+ user.VertificationCode` at the wrong place

Comment: @PranayRana Do you mean you respect me or that I should have some respect? I truly don't know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to sent html based email than you have to do like this

```
string href = String.Format(@"www.bla.com/test/ResetPasswordVertification?VertificationCode={0}", user.VertificationCode);
msg = new MailMessage("xxxx@gmail.com",
                "yyyy@gmail.com", "Message from PSSP System",
                "You have forgotten your password<br/> "+
                "so here is link to reset it<br/>" +
                "<a href='"+ href +"'>click here !</a>");

msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

you need to set flag [`IsBodyHtml`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.isbodyhtml(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: thx :) would you give example with my code , my code and structure is not like this , i also update my Question when i put a tag around

Comment: @HellorhighWater You're doing the `+ user.VertificationCode` at the wrong place

Comment: @HellorhighWater - can you please check what is written here : MailHandler().Send ...you need to do changes in that send method

Comment: @HellorhighWater - `\n ` not work in html you need to put `<br/>`

Comment: @EpicKip thats my problem , i dont where should i put + user.VertificationCode

Comment: @PranayRana thx again i will , the problem i have i dont where should i put + user.VertificationCode in a tag

Comment: @HellorhighWater Here is the sample string you need: `$"You have forgotten your password <a href=\"www.bla.com/test/ResetPasswordVertification?Vertifica‌​tionCode={user.Verif‌​icationCode}\"> Click here </a> to reset it"` I had posted it before...

Comment: @HellorhighWater See the `$` that makes it so you can do `{variable}` in strings. the `user.VerificationCode` should be after `?Vertifica‌​‌​tionCode=`

Comment: @PranayRana In case you did not know you can escape `"` with `\ ` so if you want `"` in a string you can do `\"`

Comment: @PranayRana this the code i have right now , would  you please edit this code to be right , if its possible :  new MailHandler().Send("Reset Password ", "You forgot your password \n so there is link to reset it \n <a href=\"www.bla.com/Account/loginResetPasswordVertification?VertificationCode=\">Click here</a>" + user.VertificationCode + "\n <br/> Best Regards ", Email);

Comment: @HellorhighWater Move the `+ user.VertificationCode` after the `?V‌​ertificationCode=` I told you 100x already. If you don't get this basic stuff I advice you to do a simple tutorial first

Comment: @EpicKip lol , i did and i told you wats happend , when i did and i will try 100x to figure out no problem , and ii really appreciate your help :) tnx again

Comment: @HellorhighWater You did not do that, you moved it after the `</a>` thats not what i said

Comment: @HellorhighWater - i given you buddy ..here i how you can do it string href = String.Format(@"www.bla.com/test/ResetPasswordVertification?VertificationCode={0}", user.VertificationCode); this will crete href and this create link "<a href='"+ href +"'>click here !</a>"...i dont understnad what else you need

Comment: @HellorhighWater Pranay is right, he already gave you the answer and I even gave you the exact string in comments twice now. Look where pranay has the `+ href +` the `href` is your `user.VerificationCode`

Comment: @PranayRana lets do it in chat , and problem is you put string.format and i cant put in my code

Comment: @HellorhighWater - string.format is basic function of C# ....can you start chat i dont know way ..let me see if i can start

Comment: @HellorhighWater - can you just try this string href = "www.bla.com/test/ResetPasswordVertification?VertificationCode="+user.VertificationCode; if string format is not working

Comment: @HellorhighWater - can you just try this string href = "www.bla.com/test/ResetPasswordVertification?VertificationCode="+user.VertificationCode; if string format is not working

Comment: @PranayRana my code look like this now :             new MailHandler().Send("Reset Password ", "You forgot your password \n so there is link to reset it \n <a href=\"www.bla.com/test/ResetPasswordVertification?Vertifica‌​tionCode={user.Verif‌​icationCode}\"> Click here </a>" + "\n <br/> Best Regards ", Email);
And result in mail is look like this > You forgot your password so there is link to reset it [www.bla.com/test/ResetPasswordVertification?Vertifica‌​tionCode={user.Verif‌​icationCode}]Click here 
Best Regards

Comment: @EpicKip i tried also yours get error > Unexpected character $

Comment: @HellorhighWater That means too low c# version. use `" + user.VerificationCode + "` instead

Comment: @EpicKip    this code now , please right me if i did wrong :new MailHandler().Send("Reset Password ", "You forgot your password \n så her er et link til at resette det \n <a href=\"www.bla.dk/Account/loginResetPasswordVertification?VertificationCode={user.Verif‌​icationCode}\">Klik her</a>" +" + user.VerificationCode + "+"\n <br/> Best Regards ", Email);

Comment: @HellorhighWater Last time I will help you because you don't understand the most basic of basic stuff.... `new MailHandler().Send("Reset Password ", "You forgot your password \n så her er et link til at resette det \n <a href=\"www.bla.dk/Account/loginResetPasswordVertification?Ve‌​rtificationCode=" + use‌​r.Verif‌​icationCode‌ + "​\">Klik her</a><br/> Best Regards ", Email);`

Comment: @HellorhighWater See where i put the user.VerificationCode? Now you get it finally..?

Comment: @EpicKip i dont have to explain my self , and i dont know why u mad , smile brother , and if you dont wanna help so dont,as i said i will try 100x to figure out , and  result in mail i try your code > You forgot your password så her er et link til at resette det [www.bla.dk/Account/loginResetPasswordVertification?Ve‌​‌​rtificationCode=YgVEIoEER6C78pP4zZnCrq731ybBHy​]Klik her
Best Regards

Comment: @Pranay : thx for your help , Now its link , but one thing i dont understand , even its link , but i cant open the link for ex in outlook even  bodyishtml is true

Comment: @HellorhighWater I never asked for you to explain yourself. I just said I won't help you anymore because you're doing things you clearly don't understand yet. Making a string out of multiple parts is basic stuff and you kept getting the placement wrong although I told you where to place it, you clearly did not understand the working of the `<a>` tag either as you kept placing the code in the text part of the tag.... My point practically is that you should (not must, but should) do some basic c# tutorials.

Comment: @EpicKip have you been in situation ur mind is not just working ,no matter how much u know about code , its just happend and its happend to me yesterday , where i just cant get simple thing where i worked 5 years ago in asp.net forms and today i look at in comments i just laughing my self :) so in our world its happend sometimes :)

Comment: @HellorhighWater I am a programmer for a living and have never not understood where to place the link in an `<a>` tag but whatever. If you got it working now that's good, lets not make more noise where its not needed.

Comment: @EpicKip No problemo , take care brother :)

Comment: @HellorhighWater You too ^.^

Answer (score 0):

Put the closing quote and the `</a>` tag after the user verification code.

Comment: i did , this code new MailHandler().Send("Reset Password ", "You forgot your password \n so there is link to reset it \n <a href=\"www.bla.com/Account/loginResetPasswordVertification?VertificationCode=\">Click here + user.VertificationCode</a>" + "\n <br/> Best Regards ", Email); and result in mail > You forgot your password so there is link to reset it [www.bla.com/Account/loginResetPasswordVertification?VertificationCode=]Click here + user.VertificationCode 
Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
.Send("Reset Password ", $"You have forgotten your password\n so here is link to reset it \n <a href=\"www.bla.dk/Account/loginResetPasswordVertification?VertificationCode=\{user.VertificationCode}">Click here</a>" + "\n <br/> Best Regards \n ", Email); <br>
```

Comment: new MailHandler().Send("Reset Password ", $"You have forgotten your password\n so here is link to reset it \n <a href=\"www.bla.dk/Account/loginResetPasswordVertification?VertificationCode=\{user.VertificationCode}">Click here</a>" + "\n <br/> Best Regards \n ", Email); 
get error > ) expected

Comment: Try this: new MailHandler().Send("Reset Password ", $"You have forgotten your password<br/>so here is link to reset it<br/><a href="www.bla.dk/Account/loginResetPasswordVertification?VertificationCode={user.VertificationCode}">Click here</a><br/> Best Regards", Email);

Comment: Nup Error again